# May EXC_BAD_ACCESS be related to function length?

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I have created a class in a Finite Element Method code in C++. I am using AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042.

One method in my class is fairly large, over 45k lines (after indenting it. Before, *i.e.*, line breaks only after  `;` and `}`, it was around 1.5k). I know this is bad practice, but for now I don't really see other option for what I am doing in this method.

The first instruction in this method calls another method for the same class. When I run it in serial mode (The framework I am developing in has multi-threading support) I have no problems. However, if I use the multi-thread mode(on the same computer), even with only 1 thread, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address=0x6ffffffa3280)`.

Ok, I thought I had messed up somewhere else. When I ran out of options I decided to just erase most of my colossal method, turning it into a useless but short method with just that instruction that would cause me the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. However, it did solve the problem.

The situation is something like this:

**Bad scenario**

```
//A.cpp
int A::foo() const{ return 2;}

void A::fun(const double & in_param){
    double out;
    this->func(in_param, out);
    ...
}

void A::func(const double& in_param, double &out_param){
    const int fooVar = this->foo();//EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    ...
    (45k lines of code)
    ...
}
```

**Good scenario**

```
//A.cpp
int A::foo() const{ return 2;}

void A::fun(const double & in_param){
    double out;
    this->func(in_param, out);
    ...
}

void A::func(const double& in_param, double &out_param){
    const int fooVar = this->foo();//fooVar = 2
}
```

---

Would anyone know why does this happen? And why does it happen only when multithreading?

I swear I will try to think on a way to reduce the length of the method, but I am quite curious on *why* I got that error.

Comment: This 'foo' implementation, is it really close to what you're doing in your code? Because if it is just an example the problem you are having might be in you reducing code here for ease. I would highly doubt a size of a function could ever be a problem in any way unless your stack simply fills up too much. Which would sound ridiculous to me.

Comment: Hey @AntwanvanHoudt! Thank you for taking your time to read it. The actual implementation is `int TPZHCurlNedFTriEl::Dimension() const { return TPZShapeTriang::Dimension; }` and TPZShapeTriang::Dimension is an enum.

Comment: Seems like `this` not pointing to a valid object. Check if `this` is null or pointing to a deleted object.

Comment: @guillaumeracicot, thank you. I had this feeling too, but `this` is valid. I have added some relevant context on the post: `A::func` is called by `A::fun`! If I call `A::foo` inside `A::fun`, everything is just fine (I have tried it indeed). The problem is calling `A::foo`inside `A::func`, which is the beastly large function.

Comment: @FranciscoOrlandini The only thing I can recomment to you is to split the function into many small one. This kind of code is not only unmaintainable, but also is prone to a lot of errors, like yours. I wouldn't be surprised if some hardware refuses your code. Maybe compiling in 64bit may help, but horros like this tend to be very platform specific.